# SwiftUI How would I recreate this animation?

Tags: swiftui

On instagram when you click on a post from someone profile it opens from its position. Same with the photos app. It doesnt open full screen like a navigation link or a sheet.

How would I open an image from its tile position in the same way the photos app opens a photo when you click on it?

Comment: That is a `MatchedGeometryEffect`. See [this post](https://swiftui-lab.com/matchedgeometryeffect-part1/)

Comment: @Yrb exactly what i was looking for, thanks